# Get the correct service from DI

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, service-provider

I got a class using C# and .NET 6:

```
public class MyClass()
{
   private IMyInterface _myInterface;

   public MyClass(IMyInterface interfaceInstance)
   {
      _myInterface = interfaceInstance;
   }
   ...
}
```

I have 2 different classes which implements `IMyInterface` called `ClassA` and `ClassB`.

I want to be able to make a DI twice - once for `MyClass` which receives `ClassA` as the instance in the ctr and once for `ClassB`:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   services.AddSingleton<MyClass>(sp => new MyClass(new ClassA()));
   services.AddSingleton<MyClass>(sp => new MyClass(new ClassB()));
}
```

The problem is that I don't know how to later get a specific one of them using a `ServiceProvider`

Comment: This isn't possible because there is no way to tell the difference between the two types when you resolve it by the type `MyClass`. Using .NET 6, one approach is to make the types two different via a marker interface or a derived class so you can switch between them as needed. In .NET 8, [keyed services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-8/runtime#keyed-di-services) is a supported way to handle this scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in .net 6 you can't do this directly.

So you need to either register your classes as using their own dedicated interfaces, or enumerate over them when injecting.

So to enumerate you do this.

```
public class MyClass(IEnumerable<IMyInterface > services)
{
   ...
}
```

But you still need a way to distinguish between each instance, which may or may not be possible depending on your structure.

So the best way is to make each Class dependent on a specific interface.  The interface can simply be empty.

So you have

```
public interface IMyInterface 
{
   string MyProp { get; set; }
   ...
}

public interface IMyInterfaceA: IMyInterface {} //Will be used by ClassA only
public interface IMyInterfaceB: IMyInterface {}  //Will be used by ClassB only
```

Then you have

```
services.AddSingleton<IMyInterfaceA, ClassA>();  
services.AddSingleton<IMyInterfaceB, ClassB>();
```

If you switch to .Net8 then you can use the new KeyServices option.

```
services.AddKeyedSingleton<IMyInterface , ClassA>("KeyNameClass_A");
services.AddKeyedSingleton<IMyInterface , ClassB>("KeyNameClass_B");
```

Then you can inject it like this

```
public class MyClass([FromKeyedServices("KeyNameClass_A")] IMyInterface classA)
{
 ...
}
```

(and the same for ClassB)

Comment: If you can add another approach to your answer which I actually did which is making another class which derives from MyClass and then make 2 different injections with the 2 different classes, I'll accept the answer

Comment: Well, that is a variation on the two distinct interfaces approach.  Plus, you should be really be injecting based on Interfaces (abstract) not a concrete class.